# C++ windows dll viewer

Tags: c++, windows, dll

I want to emulate an unmanaged dll in c++. Is there a good tool to open and view it's interface?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most commonly used tool is [Dependency Walker](http://dependencywalker.com/). This shows the list of exported symbols.

However, it does not show the function prototypes because they are not contained in the DLL meta data. To get that information you need a header file for the DLL. The exception to this statement are DLLs containing a COM/ActiveX component with a type library.

And even if you do have the prototypes, that's not enough to know how to emulate the DLL. You need full documentation for the DLL. And then you probably still have a lot of reverse engineering to do.

Comment: Well, if the exports have C++ signatures, then they can be demangled to include a lot of information about the parameters, calling convention, etc.

Comment: @ben true 'dat. I was being pessimistic.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - thanks, emulate was poor wording. Stub would have been closer to it's use.

Comment: @David, Why wouldn't Nirsoft's dll viewer work? http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html .